# CocoaPods was not able to update the `mapbox-mapbox-maps-ios` repo

Tags: cocoapods, mapbox-ios

pod search 'MapboxMaps' can find this library.
Then, execute 'pod repo update'.
then, execute 'pod install'.
Encountered the following issue.

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `MapboxMaps`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

pod --version
1.15.0

gem -v
3.5.5

ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2

Tried upgrading Ruby, updating CocoaPods, and refreshing the repository, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
source 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios.git'
target 'mapboxDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for mapboxDemo
  pod 'MapboxMaps'

end
```

podfile info